# How can I create and show a timer in Pascal without a Form?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I'm currently working on a Tetris game made in Pascal as a uni project, using the 'graph' unit for the graphic side of the game. Part of the assignment includes a limited time mode, where you try to get the most points before time runs out.

Now, this would imply creating a timer that updates every second, not only that, but showing it on the screen, all of this **while** the game goes on normally. It's really this part that has me confused, I can't think of a possible solution with the knowledge I have.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: As part of your game loop, read the system clock, calculate elapsed time and output it. Use elapsed time to stop the game at time out. Since you did not provide any code there's not much more to say.

Comment: A form is not required to use a TTimer object. If your app processes messages (what I guess, as your user controls the falling objects), you can set-up a timer too, triggering events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you're making a game, don't build it using LCL and components, because they're not very suitable for that. Secondly, if you want to make any meaningful game, use a dedicated library such as SDL2, Allegro or raylib — you will have access to all the useful features (regarding video, audio, gamepads etc.), not just graphics rendering.

If your game is going to run with constant framerate, the solution is very simple — count the frames because you know how many frames are processed every second. You need a frames counter so you can multiply the given time (converted to a number of seconds) by the target framerate. Then, in each game frame, decrement this counter — when it reaches the value of `0`, the game is over.

It cannot be described just like that in a few sentences, because the topic is quite extensive and there are many ways to solve this problem.

---

If you need some inspiration, a few months ago I finished my own version of Tetris (a clone of NES Tetris for Windows) called [Fairtris](https://github.com/furious-programming/Fairtris) — an open source project written in Free Pascal and SDL2 (using Lazarus). There is a [speedrun mode](https://github.com/furious-programming/Fairtris/wiki/free-speedrun) in which you have to reach level `19` starting from level `0`. The game is over if 10 minutes elapses and this mechanism works as described above.

There is another timer in Fairtris, this time a global one — it is used to count down the qualifying time, if the player has started qualifying. It also counts frames, but it works all the time — even if the player stops playing and exits to the main menu.